# Why some iOS & Android devices intermittently receive FCM topic messages?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have an android and iOS app that are setup to receive FCM topic messages.

On startup I subscribe to a topic called top_stories.
The only time a person is unsubscribed is when they toggle off a setting in the app for receiving notifications.

We send push messages via our own server with the FCM API and the payload contains both notification and data body payloads.

We recently started sending to the topic and noticed some issues. In 90% of cases all our office test devices received the push ok. However some iOS devices and some android devices had a different experience.

Two of the iOS devices didn't receive the first and second message but did receive the third message.

A similar thing happened with one android device where it received the first message, didn't receive the second and did receive the third.

Is there anything I can do to improve / fix this situation?

I can provide more details as needed regarding a sample message etc.

I know that the onMessageReceived is working ok on android in all cases as it worked during our internal testing.

We are using the following library to build the messages:

https://github.com/sngrl/php-firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the code that builds the message:

```
object(sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Message)[505]
  private 'notification' => 
    object(sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Notification)[503]
      private 'title' => string 'App Name' (length=14)
      private 'body' => string 'Upgrade testing - activation' (length=36)
      private 'badge' => null
      private 'icon' => null
      private 'sound' => string 'default' (length=7)
      private 'clickAction' => null
      private 'tag' => null
      private 'content_available' => boolean true
      private 'notification' (sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Message) => null
      private 'collapseKey' (sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Message) => null
      private 'priority' (sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Message) => null
      private 'data' (sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Message) => null
      private 'recipients' (sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Message) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private 'recipientType' (sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Message) => null
      private 'jsonData' (sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Message) => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  private 'collapseKey' => null
  private 'priority' => string 'high' (length=4)
  private 'data' => 
    array (size=7)
      'v' => int 1484232738
      'timestamp' => int 1484232738
      'pushId' => string '58779822a1fef' (length=22)
      'content_available' => boolean true
      'title' => string 'Upgrade testing - activation' (length=36)
      'articleId' => int 250324509
      'category' => string 'news/' (length=5)
  private 'recipients' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Recipient\Topic)[504]
          private 'name' => string 'top_stories_test' (length=16)
          private 'to' (sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Recipient\Recipient) => null
  private 'recipientType' => string 'sngrl\PhpFirebaseCloudMessaging\Recipient\Topic' (length=47)
  private 'jsonData' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty

{
  "to" : "/topics/top_stories",
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "Article Title",
    "title" : "Publication Name",
    "sound" : "default"
  },
  "data" : {
    "title" : "Article Title",
    "v" : "1484232738",
    "timestamp" : "1484232738",
    "pushId" : "fireabse-58779822a1fef",
    "content_available" : true,
    "title" : "Article Title",
    "articleId" : "12345",
    "category" : "news/"
  }
}
```

```xml
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1"

<service
    android:name="ie.company.services.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
    tools:ignore="ExportedService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name="ie.company.services.MyFcmListenerService"
    tools:ignore="ExportedService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Hi. Do post the relevant code snippets and sample payload messages. It's difficult to provide anything without any concrete codes/details to check.

Comment: The code and the setup looks okay. As you said, the *strange behavior* only happens on 10% of the users. Have you tried sending the notifications by using simple cURL responses only? See if the behavior is still the same? What I suspect is that there might be something with the library that's causing missing registrations. Or are you seeing a pattern on where this behavior is occurring (e.g. specific Android versions)?

Comment: @AL During development I was testing by sending via cURL from the terminal in android studio. I will test this again across all our test devices. We didn't really see any patterns so far, one of our testers is keeping track of which devices are receiving each push to see. Its also happened on iOS as well.

Comment: @AL. I am currently updating the spreadsheet with the details on which devices received which push, would this be any help to you?

Comment: Hi. I'm fairly sure that there is no issue with FCM on this matter. It works on 90% of the users. Is it possible that the behavior is only device specific? Were you able to replicate it when only sending the messages through cURL?

Comment: @AL. I will get the tester to verify this today and get back to you. Only one of the devices a HTC with Marshmallow received all the push messages, all our other test devices missed at least one.

Comment: @AL. Our tester sent messages using cURL to some of the devices today without issue. Also on another note, before we released the production version we tested a lot on our own devices with a top_stories_test topic, however we never had any issues with messages sent to that topic.